# Cannot use API 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<file_id>/export?mimeType=image%2Fjpeg' to get image from google drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, mime-types

My problem is that i can't get image on google drive when using 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<file_id>/export?mimeType=image%2Fjpeg'

#### Here, my code:

```
from pydrive import auth, drive
import requests

gauth = auth.GoogleAuth()
scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
gauth.credentials = auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('my_json.json', scope)
drv = drive.GoogleDrive(gauth)
access_token = drv.auth.credentials.get_access_token().access_token
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + file_id + '/export?mimeType=image%2Fjpeg'
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token})
```

#### Respone error (403):

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I just reuqest 10-20 times. This error response seem wrong.

How i can fix above code to get response ?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What is the mimeType of the original file you are trying to export?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tanaike My original file is *.jpg. I used mimeType=image/jpeg

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: No problem. I am very grateful for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `My original file is *.jpg. I used mimeType=image/jpeg` and your script, you want to download a JPEG file from Google Drive using the service account.

#### Modification points:

- When you want to download a JPEG file, I think that your endpoint is required to be modified.
- I think that when the access token is not used for the endpoint, the error of `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.` occurs. But, when the invalid access token is used, an error of `Invalid Credentials` occurs. In your script, even when the access token is invalid, I think that an error of `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.` doesn't occur. So I'm worried that your showing script might be different from your tested script. Please confirm this again.

If a JPEG file is downloaded from Google Drive using the service account, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
from pydrive import auth, drive
import requests

file_id = "###"  # Please set the file ID of the JPEG file.

gauth = auth.GoogleAuth()
scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
gauth.credentials = auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('my_json.json', scope)
drv = drive.GoogleDrive(gauth)
access_token = drv.auth.credentials.get_access_token().access_token
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file_id + "?alt=media"
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})
```

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that your service account can access the JPEG file on Google Drive. Please be careful about this. If an error like `File not found` occurs, please check about this, again.
- For example, when you want to download a JPEG file using pydrive, you can also the following script.

  ```
    from pydrive import auth, drive
    import requests

    file_id = "###"  # Please set the file ID of the JPEG file.

    gauth = auth.GoogleAuth()
    scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    gauth.credentials = auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('my_json.json', scope)
    drv = drive.GoogleDrive(gauth)
    drv.CreateFile({"id": file_id}).GetContentFile("sample.jpg")
  ```

#### References:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads)
- [PyDrive](https://github.com/googlearchive/PyDrive)

Comment: Amazing! It's worked. Thanks so much, i love you @Tainaike :))

Comment: @Tai Lu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.